# File used by another process exception

Tags: c#, xml, windows

I have two C# .NET applications:

- One application (lets say App1) writes data to XML file.
- The second application (lets call it App2) reads data from the same
  XML file and updates itself.

App2 continuously monitors for the changes in XML file, for which I am using `FileSystemWatcher`.

As soon as the App1 completes writing to the file, App2 reads the changes.

I made sure my App2 is reading the XML only with Read access, but still sometimes my App1 throws an exception:

> "The process cannot access the file 'C:\xmlFile' because it is being used by another process". Here is my code snippet in App2 which is reading the file.

Here is my code:

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Only detect start elements.
            if (reader.IsStartElement())
            {
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                    case "Component":
                        fileElements.ComponentName = reader["Name"];
                        fileElements.DateRun = reader["DateRun"];
                        fileElements.Passed = reader["Passed"];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (filePath.ToLower().Contains("ebsserver"))
        {
            UpdateDataTable1(fileElements);
        }
        else if (filePath.ToLower().Contains("ebsui"))
        {
            UpdateDataTable2(fileElements);
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateDataTable3(fileElements);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just because you specify read only doesn't mean it can open the file if another process owns it. You need to verify that App1 has closed the file before App2 can open it. Since App1 may flush to the file and cause a file change notification before closing, its entirely possible you run into collisions.

Comment: FileAccess does not affect sharing. It affects the permissions your process has, not other processes. Both applications need to open the file with the proper sharing permission. App2 looks like it should use FileShare.ReadWrite. The default is FileShare.None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `FileShare.ReadWrite` in the reading app to signalize that there will be no lock when opening. It's the same mechanism that is used in, for instance, text editors which open files which are also written to.

```
File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

Comment: It's `None` by default. That's why you have this exception. I had this issue myself recently when I tried to read log files which were under constant write access. After this, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will try and let you know. I am seeing this issue once in 24 hours or so. I will let it run with this change over night  and verify

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the FileShare parameter on the File.Open method

```
    using (var stream = File.Open(filePath,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Only detect start elements.
            if (!reader.IsStartElement())
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (reader.Name != "Component")
            {
                continue;
            }

            fileElements.ComponentName  = reader["Name"];
            fileElements.DateRun        = reader["DateRun"];
            fileElements.Passed         = reader["Passed"];
       }

       if (filePath.ToLower().Contains("ebsserver"))
       {
           UpdateDataTable1(fileElements);
       }
       else if (filePath.ToLower().Contains("ebsui"))
       {
           UpdateDataTable2(fileElements);
       }
       else
       {
           UpdateDataTable3(fileElements);
       }
   }
```

Comment: I would agree and just delete it normally, but it isn't because the answer also demonstrates to the OP how to keep his code clean, I've cleaned it up making it more legible and removed unnecessary bits of code, if you compare the two you'll see what I mean. That said, you did post before me so +1 from me

Comment: Well, to be honest, I think vertical alignment of code isn't very good practice in C# because of Visual Studio's auto formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, I was talking about the nested if statements and the unnecessary switch statement

Comment: That's more or less a matter of taste. I would prefer to put both equations into one `if`. But the vertically aligned 3 lines below that will be formatted by Visual Studio to what they look like in the OP.